# Move data from one string to another

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, math

I am writing a calculator for a school project. I ran into  a problem when parsing form in c# program using VBScript `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl().Eval()`. That is alright, except for logarithms. VBS cant do c# logarithms with custom base so I need to use an equation to reform it.

I need to get from `log10(x)` to `(log(x)/log(10))` or from `log(x, a)` where `a` is base to `(log(x)/log(a)`.

I've tried to search but I can't really find a way to grab two values and put them in a different way. And as I'm a little new to c#, I couldn't come up with better idea than RegEx
Thanks for help

Comment: it will be easier to do it in two different regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Eval in VBScript is your problem, try Mono.CSharp which has got Evaluator.Eval method and it pretty much Eval anything which you can in C#.
Here is the link to download [David Ebbo's blog about Mono CSharp Compiler Service](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/02/quick-fun-with-monos-csharp-compiler-as.html)

Comment: That would be one way but is there anything in .NET purely?

Comment: Mono is based upon c#.  As far as pure .net solution is concetned, You will have to use Reflection to achieve this.